# Use the PC speaker's beep with Game Maker

Tags: beep, game-maker

Is there anything in Game Maker that allows to use the PC speaker to produce a beep? I would like to use it in order to create musics for old-school video games. I tried to find something related in the documentation but was not able to find anything about such a thing.

Comment: Assuming you're using a recent version of Windows (Vista or newer), you'll have quite a bit of trouble making the PC speaker beep at all: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/larryosterman/archive/2010/01/04/what-s-up-with-the-beep-driver-in-windows-7.aspx

Comment: you can extend GM with DLLs, so use existing one or create to provide this functionality

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an original idea, but I wouldn't recommend doing it for a couple of reasons.

1] What if the player is using headphones? 
2] Will you be able to control the volume of the beeps?
3] You will have to use DLL which may not be supported by all operating systems (or versions).

If you really want to use it, then use this extension: http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=324737

Answer (score 0):

I think this DLL might be more fit for purpose, yet I am still not sure if it will yield any good results, since I'm pretty sure you will not get perfect notes out of it. It could be fun though. :)

http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=473547

Comment: Please [do not post an answer that consists essentially of a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). Include the important points in your answer; leave the link for extra information or as a reference.